# Efficient Site Structure

Tags: php, html

I need to make some websites for work. I am new to it, so I am going pretty basic with bootstrap. There are a number of pages that will be identically structured, just with different text and links.

My question is, can I have a template php file that just reads a formatting txt file, or something along those lines? I am just hoping that I can manage one master file that keeps the structure consistent across all pages, but be able to tweak each page with a simple file that only changes what is needed.

I hope that makes sense. Please let me know if I need to clarify, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need a header PHP script which loads all the CSS files, and the core bits of HTML which define the layout etc. Then you include that script in all your page files. And include a footer script at the bottom to close off the HTML tags you opened in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an includes page in your php structure. This page will have functions that create each structure of your pages that are the same. For example, you may have external links that are all the same that you use on each of your pages, you may also have a header and nav bar, maybe a sidebar and a footer that are all the same. On the `includes.php` page you have functions that builds each of these components.

Following would be an example of a head section with a nav and single div section you may want to use on multiple pages you may also include a definitions page that defines different variables or defines that can be used in each page as well.

```php
function evalPath($page){
    switch ($page){
        case "home":
            $path = "";
            break;
        default:
            $path = "../";
    }    
    return $path;
};

function constructHead($page, $metaDesc, $metaKeywords, $otherLinks, $siteroot){
$path = evalPath($page);
    $stmt = "    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang=\"en\">
        <head>
            <meta charset=\"utf-8\">    
            <meta name=\"description\" content=\"".$metaDesc."\">
            <meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"".$metaKeywords."\">
            <meta name=\"author\" content=\"".META['author']."\">
            <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no\">    
            ".$otherLinks."
            
            <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='$siteroot/css/main.css'>
            
            <link rel=\"icon\" href=\"".$path."favicon.png\">
            
            <title>".$title."</title>
            
        
        </head>    
        ";
    return $stmt;
}

function constructSingleDiv($spans, $content){
    $stmt = "
        <div id='cont' class='container'>
            <div class='".$spans."'>". $content."</div><!--/END .'.$spans.' -->
        </div>";
    return $stmt;
}

function constructNav($page, $siteroot){ //$page is the body id of the page calling the function and is defined on the page 
                              //example: 
                              ##################################################
                              #### $page = 'home'; --> <body id='.$page.'>  ####
                              ##################################################
    
    $path = evalPath($page);
    $stmt = '
        <div id="top-nav"><a class="adminLogin" href="'.$siteroot.'/admin/index.php">Login</a>
            <ul id="nav_bar" class="nav">
                <li class="home">
                    <a href="'.$siteroot.'/index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li  class="media">
                    <a href="#media">Media</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="music"><a href="#music">Music</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class=""><a href="#">Foil</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#">Long Drive home</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#">Sunday Girl</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>    
                        <li class="video"><a href="'.$siteroot.'/pages/video.php">Video</a></li>            

                        <li class="art"><a href="'.$siteroot.'/pages/art.php">Art</a></li>            

                        <li class="pictures"><a href="'.$siteroot.'/pages/pictures.php">Pictures</a></li>

                        <li class="web"><a href="'.$siteroot.'/pages/web.php">Web</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li><!-- END li.media -->
                <li class="contact">
                    <a href="'.$siteroot.'/pages/contact.php">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="blog">
                    <a href="'.$siteroot.'/pages/blog.php">Blog</a>       
                </li>
                
                    
                
            </ul><!-- END ul.nav -->
        </div><!-- END div#top-nav -->';
        //<p>current page is: '.$page.'</p>
    return $stmt;
    
}
```

Now on my page where I wish to reuse this component of code I simply add an include function to include that file in the page then call on the function and pass the variables that add the content for each function I wish to use.

`include 'includes.php';`

Then to call my head section, I simply add the function...

`constructHead($page, $metaDesc, $metaKeywords, $otherLinks, $siteroot);`

Now above these functions that I call coming from my includes.php page, I need to define those variables I am passing into the functions... These variables are the content that is relevant to the page I am calling the  function from the includes page on. The HTML or structure will be the same however the content will be defined on the page locally.

So on my `home.php` I may define those variables as such...

```php
// JUST below the opening php tag place the include statement
include 'includes/functions.php';

$page = 'home';
$metaDesc = 'A few lines that describe what my page is about.';
$metaKeywords = 'code, coding, php, incudes, fucntions';
$otherLinks = 'scripts/js/index.js';
$siteroot = 'https://mypage.php';
$content = 'Something I want to say about my home page';
```

This example is very simple but you can see how this works.

[include in php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
[require in php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

Comment: This is what I was after. Thanks for the detailed response!

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite broad and opinion-based but I can share how I would organize it:

**Big picture**
First of all, I suggest doing *mise en place* it is a French term used in the kitchen. It means that you should prepare/assemble everything and put the things where they belong before you start cooking in order to speed up the process. In our case, it means we should think about the big picture first. The goal, the tools, resources, concepts, and how everything is linked. It is easier to write the whole plan down before you start - then you will see if you are missing something or what you can do differently or where you need further investigation.

**Separation of concerns**
So to start we have backend and frontend. `PHP` is on the backend-, `JavaScript`, and `CSS` on the frontend side. As you know in `PHP` we can do lots of things e.g. init, load, print, modify, configure, and so forth. The data may stem from a local or external source. We can also print `CSS` and `JavaScript` code. Even though we can do it, we should separate the concerns i.e. each script and style should have it's own place or file where it lives.

**Styles**
I recommend using [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax) or [SASS](https://sass-lang.com) for your styles. These `CSS` pre-compilers are quite handy and reduce boilerplate code. You can also use mixins and variables.
There is also the option to combine multiple style files into one, minify and therefore optimize the overall load time.

You may also like reset css or twitter bootstrap for a start. The [reset css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reset-css) does address a few common cross-browser style issues. Such as font-scaling, line-heights, and the like. Twitter bootstrap adds out of the box components that you can easily use and you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

**Scripts**
If you want to keep it simple write vanilla javascript code here or include some libraries maybe. Is jQuery still a thing? For a start why not? Bootstrap has some components that use javascript. You can also combine multiple script files into one here and then minify.

**Templates**
In the template folder, you can add `PHP` files, that are used across multiple sites e.g. a header or footer. Maybe you want to create your own components as well that can be used on different sites. On top of that, you could have alternative or fallback files for e.g. different header/footer files for different pages.

**The examples below contain more or less `PHP` code, but it is not functional, just abstract. You can do it however you please.**

example header.php

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- you could have a foreach loop here or just pass it as a string -->
    <?php echo $metas; ?>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

    <!-- begin styles -->
    <?php echo $styles; ?>
    <!-- end styles -->

    <!-- begin scripts -->
    <?php echo $scripts; ?>
    <!-- end scripts -->
</head>
<body>
```

example about.php

```php
<?php
  $metas = [...];   // could be site specific or global
  $styles = [...];  // ...
  $scripts = [...]; // ...
  $title = 'About';
?>
<?php require('header.php'); ?>

<div>
    <h2>About us</h2>
    // ...
</div>

<?php require('footer.php'); ?>
```

example footer.php

```php
  <footer>
    <div>Footer ...</div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**Sites**
These could be the actual pages, that you want to represent on your website. For example, `about.php` handles the `/about` page and you can access it via `www.example.com/about`. It really depends on what your goal is. You can reuse the headers, footers, components, and other templates here.

**Structure**
Let us have a look at a possible, simplified file structure for this:

```
./
├── styles/
│   ├── css/
│       └── componentX.css     // compiled css files from scss/sass
│   ├── componentX.sass        // custom css files per component
│   └── vendor/
│       └── bootstrap.min.css  // external css files
├── scripts/
│   ├── global.js              // custom js files for all sites
│   ├── componentX.js          // custom js files per component
│   └── vendor/
│       └── bootstrap.min.js   // external js files
├── images/
│   ├── banner.png             // images, icons, svgs
│   ├── favicon.ico            // 
│   └── logo.svg               //
├── fonts/
│   ├── font.ttf               // various fonts
│   └── font.eot               //
├── templates/
│   ├── header.php             // standard header template
│   ├── footer.php             // standard footer template
│   └── componentX.php         // custom template, each component (or fallback)
├── pages/
│   ├── about.php              // www.example.com/about
│   ├── products.php           // www.example.com/products
│   └── sitemap.php            // www.example.com/sitemap
├── index.php                  // can be used for bootstrapping / setup
└── .htaccess                  // rewrite rules, access restrictions etc.
```

**Bootstrap, access management, routing**
You can use .htaccess to pass all requests through `index.php` and inside of it and set up your routes, paths, services, your database connection, and whatever you may need.

You may want to look at the [MVC pattern](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller), routing and [spl-autoload](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah!  So normally with PHP sites I usually had this format:

SomePage.php:

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
Content Here
<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

header.php:

```
<link href="mycss.css">
<nav> .. menu here
```

footer.php:

```
<script src="myglobal.js"></script>
```

This is an easy approach to learn from.  Later on, you'll want invert the approach, and use Template Inheritance. Learn more about Template Inheritance here: https://arshaw.com/phpti/

Comment: Thanks for the template inheritance link, that was helpful.